# SSRS - Parser Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I facing the issue that mention error for SSRS report.
I'm currently using VS2015 for development.

Here is the error that i facing now.
I have no idea how to solve this problem.

**Should I install the report viewer?**

**Parser Error**

**Description**: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

**Parser Error Message**: The base class includes the field 'ReportViewerSummary', but its type (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer) is not compatible with the type of control (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer).

**Source Error:**

```
Line 12:         <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" ScrollBars="Horizontal">
Line 13:         <asp:Label ID="LableWarning" CssClass="LableWarning" runat="server" />
Line 14:         <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewerSummary" runat="server" Width="100%">
Line 15:         </rsweb:ReportViewer>
Line 16:        </asp:Panel>
```

**Source File**: /DCBRequestLogSummary.aspx    Line: 14 
**Version Information**: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1586.0

**In the Designer error**

**Error Creating Control**

Failed to create designer'Microsoft.Reporting,WebForms,ReportViewer, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicToken=xxxx'

Thank you

Comment: Is this due to having a different version of the dll to the one that is referenced? This would happen if you actually have version 10 installed but are trying to reference version 11.

Comment: Hi DeanOC, i think possible because when i remove the version 10 and add in the version 11  ReportViewer.Webform.dll will cause the error and after that i remove the version 11 add in version 10 did not caused any error.

I think no just need to match the Microsoft.ReportViewer,WebForms only